# Fetch records from Mysql database into jquery script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Am adding new table row using onclick function. I want to get records from MySql into a select option tag when a new row is added.

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".add").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td> <select id="credit_1" name="account_code[]" class="form-custom-control" style="padding-top:0px;"><option></option></select></td>';
    html += '<td>
                 <select name="fund_id[]" class="form-custom-control">
                     <option></option>
                </select>
             </td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="category[]" id="category_'+i+'"></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});
```

**Ajax**

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".add",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this=$(this);
    var id =_this.val();
    var fund=_this.closest("tr").find("select[name='fund_id[]']");
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "populate_fund_type.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
               fund.html(html);
           } 
      });
  });
});
```

**Php**

```
     $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = $link->query("SELECT * FROM funds");
     echo '<option></option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['fund_id'].'">'.$row['fund_name'].'</option>'; 
   }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you seem to not be aware that PHP is server-side. Document yourself on how to perform an AJAX request using jquery and then move the PHP code elsewhere (you will figure it out when you get there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ajax and jquery for this.and on success append html into the div or table.
ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'yourphp_page.php',
    data: {status:"0"}
}).done(function(html){     
$('#yourtable_id').append(html);

});
```